# C++ toUpper Implementation

Tags: c++, implementation, toupper

I made an implementation of toUpper(). It doesn't work 100%.

**Code :**

```
char* toUpper(char* string)
{
    char* sv = string;
    while(*sv++ != '\0')
    {
        if( int(*sv) >= 97 || int(*sv) <= 122)  //Only if it's a lower letter
            *sv = char( *sv - 32);
    }
    return string;
}
```

I know that the lower letters have the numbers from 97 to 122 (in ASCII) and the upper letters have the numbers from 65 to 90. There are exactly 32 numbers between the lower to the upper letter. So I just subtracted 32 from the lower character.

**Code where I call this function :**

```
char h[] = "Whats up?";
cout << toUpper(h) << endl;
```

I expected the program to output **"WHATS UP?"** but instead I got **"WHATS"**. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you doing this for educational purposes?

Comment: Your `while` loop is off by one character (the one you test in the predicate isn't the same you test/change in the body). You should change it to an appropriate `for` loop or at least move the pointer incrementation at the end of the loop body.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yeah, why?

Comment: `if( int(*sv) >= 97 || int(*sv) <= 122)  //Only if it's a lower letter` <-- this will always be true

Comment: @Davlog:  Just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if( int(*sv) >= 97 || int(*sv) <= 122)
```

should be

```
if( int(*sv) >= 97 && int(*sv) <= 122)
```

or, preferably

```
if( *sv >= 'a' && *sv <= 'z')
    *sv = *sv - ('a' - 'A');
```

You also need to move the point at which you increment `sv`.  The current code skips checking the first character in `string`

```
while(*sv != '\0')
{
    if( *sv >= 'a' && *sv <= 'z')
        *sv = *sv - ('a' - 'A');
    sv++;
}
```

Lastly, I'm sure you're aware of it but just in case... if this isn't a homework assignment or other learning exercise, the standard C [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) function will do exactly the same job for you

```
*sv = (char)toupper(*sv);
```

Comment: Precisely. Space (`' '`) is ASCII 32, so subtracting 32 yields a NUL, causing `cout` to stop there.

Comment: The space character is decimal 32, so the original code fails because the if statement is true, you subtract 32, and therefore your next check on the while loop returns false.

Answer (score 2):

Having ++ in the while makes you miss important cases. The int() things are unnecessary noise. You need && in the check condition. The action can be written with -=.

Comment: Why does having ++ in my while make me miss important cases?

Comment: @Davlog It means you increment `sv` before the first check for a lower case character.  So `"hello"` would be converted to `"hELLO"`

Comment: Hmm.. you're right! The first letter was already an upper letter, so I didn't notice :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rewrite that uses a for loop and fixes your conditional as well as off-by-one increment:

```
char* toUpper(char* string)
{
    for(char* p=string; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        if(*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z')  //Only if it's a lower letter
          *p -= 32;
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Where is sv declared and defined?